# How can I change drop down box #2 based on input from drop down box #1?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have two drop down menus.

```
<form action="form.php" class="inputlabels" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_asset" method="post">
    <select id="asset_id" name="asset[asset_id]">
        <option value="1">Trailer 1 - Spanish</option>
        <option value="2">Trailer 1 - English</option>
        <option value="3">Trailer 1 - French</option>
        <option value="4">Trailer 1 - German</option>
        <option value="5">Trailer 2 - Spanish</option>
        <option value="6">Trailer 2 - English</option>
        <option value="7">Trailer 2 - French</option>
        <option value="8">Trailer 2 - German</option>
    </select>
<br />
    <select id="country_id" name="material[country_id]">
        <option value="11">England</option>
        <option value="12">Spain</option>
        <option value="13">France</option>
        <option value="14">Germany</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want for drop down menu 2 to automatically change based on the value of menu 1. I need to be able to declare that when a user selects "Trailer 1 - Spanish" or "Trailer 2 - Spanish", the  country is automatically selected as Spain. The idea is that it saves the user from having to select the country.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be very valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need (Also handles the other languages):

**HTML**

```
<select id="asset_id" name="asset[asset_id]">
    <option value=""> - Select Trailer - </option>
    <option value="1">Trailer 1 - Spanish</option>
    <option value="2">Trailer 1 - English</option>
    <option value="3">Trailer 1 - French</option>
    <option value="4">Trailer 1 - German</option>
    <option value="5">Trailer 2 - Spanish</option>
    <option value="6">Trailer 2 - English</option>
    <option value="7">Trailer 2 - French</option>
    <option value="8">Trailer 2 - German</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="country_id" name="material[country_id]">
    <option value=""> - Select Country - </option>
    <option value="11">England</option>
    <option value="12">Spain</option>
    <option value="13">France</option>
    <option value="14">Germany</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ddl1 = document.getElementById( 'asset_id' );

function updateCountry ( e ) {

    var asset = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,
        countryDDL= document.getElementById( 'country_id' ),
        country, i = countryDDL.options.length - 1;

    switch ( asset ) {
        case "1":
            country = 12;
            break;
        case "2":
            country = 11;
            break;
        case "3":
            country = 13;
            break;
        case "4":
            country = 14;
            break;
        case "5":
            country = 12;
            break;
        case "6":
            country = 11;
            break;
        case "7":
            country = 13;
            break;
        case "8":
            country = 14;
            break;
    }

    for ( ; i > -1 ; i-- ) {

        if ( countryDDL.options[i].value == country ) {
            countryDDL.options[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }

    }

}

ddl1.onchange = updateCountry;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/uVMZF/

Comment: Mark this as your answer pls! Ô_O

Comment: Times like these I miss VB.NET's switches, where multiple values can evaluate to the same case. That's about all I miss from VB.NET. =)

Comment: @AntonCooper Don't forget to upvote him as well. The more you get into this site, the more you'll want those points!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dropdowns are dynamically built, I'd have your server generate a little javascript for you - the PHP code can map them, so the output looks something like:

```
var _languageMap = {
    { 1: 12 },
    { 2: 11 },
    ...
    { 8: 14 }
};
```

Then set an eventhandler on change of your first dropdown, and set the second by looking up the value from your language map. If you're using jQuery, try something like:

```
jQuery("#asset_id").change(function() {
    var trailerId = jQuery(this).val();
    var languageId = _languageMap[trailerId];
    jQuery("#country_id").val(languageId);
});
```

If you're not using jQuery, you can do the same with regular javascript - you'll just need to look up event handlers for dropdown lists - I just don't remember how to do that the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

### [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCre6/)

Markup

```
<select id="asset_id" name="asset[asset_id]" onchange="selectCountry()">
```

Javascript

```
function selectCountry()
{
   var asset = document.getElementById('asset_id');
   var assetText = asset.options[asset.selectedIndex].text;



    var country_id = document.getElementById('country_id');

    if(assetText.toLowerCase().indexOf('spanish') > -1)
       country_id.value = 12;  //spain
    else if(assetText.toLowerCase().indexOf('german') > -1)
       country_id.value = 14;  //germany
    else if(assetText.toLowerCase().indexOf('english') > -1)
       country_id.value = 11;  //england
    else if(assetText.toLowerCase().indexOf('french') > -1)
       country_id.value = 13;  //france
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a second dropdown doesn't make a lot of sense then if they're related that way, unless the user can select a combination of trailers and countries that don't match. Why not make your first control a dropdown, add a data-* attribute to the options and fill a label for the user.

So, your options would look something like this:

```
<option id="optT1Span" value="1" data-country="Spain">Trailer 1 - Spanish</option>
```

If you need the values from the second option, you can just set up a global array lookup of those country/value combinations.

Obviously, I don't know the thoughts behind your design or what you have planned, but if the selections must match, then I don't see the point of giving the ability to select a country. It almost makes more sense to filter by your country and then hide/show options based on that selection more than what you have planned. I feel you always remove as many avenues of user interaction as you can if they aren't necessary.