# Javascript based on value in one drop down bow changes values in 2 other drop down boxes

Tags: javascript

Based on example https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104169/2465936 want to create such behavior:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/Ppbk5/17/

3 drop down boxes. User chooses value in the first drop down box. If for example user choses Option 2 or Option 3 in the first drop down box, then value in the second and third drop down boxes changes to blank `<option value="4"></option>`

Here is HTML

```
<select id="asset_id" name="asset[asset_id]">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4"></option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="country_id" name="material[country_id]">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4"></option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="country_id1" name="material1[country_id1]">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4"></option>
</select>
```

And here is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var ddl1 = document.getElementById( 'asset_id' );
function updateCountry ( e ) {

var asset = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, countryDDL= document.getElementById( 'country_id' ), country, i = countryDDL.options.length - 1;

switch ( asset ) {
case "2": country = 4;
break;
case "3": country = 4;
break;
}

for ( ; i > -1 ; i-- ) {
if ( countryDDL.options[i].value == country ) {
countryDDL.options[i].selected = true;
break;
}
}

}

ddl1.onchange = updateCountry;
});

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var ddl2 = document.getElementById( 'asset_id' );
function updateCountry1 ( e ) {

var asset1 = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, countryDDL1= document.getElementById( 'country_id1' ), country1, i = countryDDL1.options.length - 1;

switch ( asset1 ) {
case "2": country1 = 4;
break;
case "3": country1 = 4;
break;

}

for ( ; i > -1 ; i-- ) {
if ( countryDDL1.options[i].value == country1 ) {
countryDDL1.options[i].selected = true;
break;
}
}

}

ddl2.onchange = updateCountry1;
});

</script>
```

Code changes `<option value="4"></option>` only in one drop down box. I simply copied-paste javascript and modified variable and values. Something done incorrectly. And possible can do it with one javascript code.

Could you advice what is incorrect?

**Update**

Based on answer such code may be used

```
function blank() {
if ( document.getElementById('assed_id').selectedIndex == 2 ) {
document.getElementById('country_id').selectedIndex=4;
document.getElementById('country_id1').selectedIndex=4;
}
}
```

But need to think how to change javascript if drop down boxes are created using php array with foreach....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first select option add the on change method to blank other two select option

```
<select id="asset_id" name="asset[asset_id]" onchange="blank(this.value)">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4"></option>
</select>
```

add in script blank function to set the value of other select option

```
<script>
function blank(ch)
{
    if(ch!=1)
    {
    document.getElementById('country_id').selectedIndex=4;
    document.getElementById('country_id1').selectedIndex=4;
    }  

}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I marked as accepted, but it changes to blank also if I choose Option 1. Suppose need to create some condition....