# How in MVC accumulate data in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am just started learn Web Application Programming and will appreciate any help.
I am using MVC 4 and the problem I trying to solve is:
I want to calculate total energy spent in daily activities.
I have 20 different categories of activities. Each of these categories has subcategories mapped into DB table.
I want repeatedly to select categories in the view. For selected category get data from table and select any number of subcategories and show them in the main view. 
I solved this in a way which probably the worst (according to performance). I will appreciate any help.
Here is my approach:
I select a category in the View_1 and pass it into the View_2.  I make selections in View_2 and submit them to controller C_2 , where selected items are accumulated  in the TempData. I put all accumulated items at the final stage into a Model.

Comment: So, you Have Parents and Children...and when a user selects a Parent you want to show them all the possible Children? Could you perhaps create a ViewModel which has a Parent, and List<Children>. Load it all when the page is loaded, and when the selection changes on the Parent have it change the values of the DropDown Box using a javascript framework?

Comment: Check this article out I found - I unfortunately am not a javascript expert but this looks like it accomplishes that you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104046/how-can-i-change-drop-down-box-2-based-on-input-from-drop-down-box-1

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. Sorry, probably my case description was not precise. 
My case similar to a shopping cart: 
There are different categories of products: TV sets, computers etc. As soon the category was chosen  set of products appears where you make selections. Selected items with their prices are accumulated in shopping cart.  This selection  goes on until you done and proceed further.